# Dotnet 5 web Api working localhost not in production! upload video

Tags: c#, .net, restful-url

Hi guys I've been trying to solver this problem on the past days but I could not find a answer!
I'm using docker/Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.15.0 x86_64)/Nginx
All the entry point is working fine even on the server but when I try to upload a video I received this message!

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[1]
  An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
  System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file '/Users/thiagodias/Desktop/Beginner to Pro/4. Displaying Data and Handling Events/6- Style Binding.mp4'.
  File name: '/Users/thiagodias/Desktop/Beginner to Pro/4. Displaying Data and Handling Events/6- Style Binding.mp4'
     at System.IO.FileInfo.get_Length()
     at Vimeo.UploadFile(String filePath, VimeoVideoProperties properties) in /src/Services/Vimeo.cs:line 193
     at SprintBlueAPI.Services.UserService.VimeoUpload(String path) in /src/Services/UserService.cs:line 90
     at SprintBlueAPI.Services.UserService.RegisterProductModuleSection(ProductModuleSection model) in /src/Services/UserService.cs:line 371
     at SprintBlueAPI.Controllers.UsersController.RegisterProductModuleSection(ProductModuleSectionModel model) in /src/Controllers/UsersController.cs:line 160
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.TaskOfIActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask)
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeInnerFilterAsync>g__Awaited|13_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|19_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.Policy.AuthorizationMiddlewareResultHandler.HandleAsync(RequestDelegate next, HttpContext context, AuthorizationPolicy policy, PolicyAuthorizationResult authorizeResult)
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
     at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
     at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

on my Nginx default

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
listen [::]:80 default_server;
proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:5000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
}
```

``

*Program.cs*

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
        {
            webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
        });
}
```

*Startup.cs*

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<ForwardedHeadersOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.KnownProxies.Add(IPAddress.Parse("10.0.0.100"));
        });
        services.AddAutoMapper(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());
        var connection = Configuration["DefaultConnection"];
        var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Configuration["Secret"]);
        
        services.AddAuthentication(x =>
        {
            x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddJwtBearer(x =>
        {
            x.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
            {
                OnTokenValidated = context =>
                {
                    var userService = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IUserService>();
                    //var userId = int.Parse(context.Principal.Identity.Name);
                    //var user = userService.GetById(userId);

                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                }
            };
            x.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
            x.SaveToken = true;
            x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
                ValidateIssuer = false,
                ValidateAudience = false
            };
        });
        services.AddDbContext<Services.DbContext>(options => options.UseMySql(connection, new MySqlServerVersion(new Version())));
        services.AddCors(options => {
            options.AddPolicy("AllowAll", builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader());
            
        });
        services.AddControllers();
        
        services.AddScoped<IUserService, UserService>();
        services.AddSwaggerGen(swagger =>
        {
            //This is to generate the Default UI of Swagger Documentation  
            swagger.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo
            {
                Version = "v1",
                Title = "JWT Token Authentication API",
                Description = "ASP.NET Core 5.0 Web API"
            });
            // To Enable authorization using Swagger (JWT)  
            swagger.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new OpenApiSecurityScheme()
            {
                Name = "Authorization",
                Type = SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey,
                Scheme = "Bearer",
                BearerFormat = "JWT",
                In = ParameterLocation.Header,
                Description = "JWT Authorization header using the Bearer scheme. \r\n\r\n Enter 'Bearer' [space] and then your token in the text input below.\r\n\r\nExample: \"Bearer 12345abcdef\"",
            });
            swagger.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
            {
                {
                    new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                    {
                        Reference = new OpenApiReference
                        {
                            Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                            Id = "Bearer"
                        }
                    },
                    new string[] {}
                }
            });
        });
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseSwagger();
            app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "API v1"));
        }
        if (env.IsProduction())
        {
            app.UseHsts();
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseSwagger();
            app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "API v1"));
        }
        Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);

        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseCors();
        app.UseDefaultFiles(); // index.html, default.html, and so on
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
        {
            ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
        });

        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
    }
}
```

}

The path of the video is correct is the same that I'm uploading on the localhost.

Anyone had the same problem? Can give me some light please ! Tks.

Comment: Please post the exception as *text* within your question rather than as an image.

Comment: You didn't post the code that stores the file. Does the path you save to exist *inside the Docker container?*

Comment: its upload to Vimeo and saving the vimeoPath to the database

Comment: Your server-side code is attempting to access a file using what looks like client-side path. I think the issue is going to be in the client-side code that uploads the file.

Comment: Basically I'm forwarding the path to the api upload! My controller is like this. `[Authorize]
    [EnableCors("AllowAll")] 
    [Route("[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class UsersController : ControllerBase`

and the controller is receiving`[EnableCors]
        [HttpPost("registerProductModuleSection")]
        [DisableRequestSizeLimit]
        public async Task<IActionResult> RegisterProductModuleSection(ProductModuleSectionModel model)` where this model contains the path of the file

Comment: You can't just pass a path from the client to the server and expect the server to be able to use it. Normally (i.e., in production) they are two separate machines, so the client-side path will have no meaning on the server. Start here, and pay particular attention to the HTML side of things: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-5.0